# How can I turn the 'Quick Favorites' menu into a pie menu with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu, quick-favorites

I'm looking for a way to turn the list of quick favorites into a pie menu.
I don't want to hard code every one of them in the addon, I just want the pie menu to update automatically when I add a tool to the quick favorites.
After some digging I found out that this information is stored in the preferences, but I can't find a way to read out that list.